# Are threadsafe CXF calls blocking other calls?

Tags: soap, thread-safety, cxf

We are planning to use CXF to generate Java classes for our Java client code. And I've read that CXF is thread-safe see [CXF FAQ](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAXWSclientproxiesthreadsafe%3F).

But what I cannot find is whether 2 calls in 2 threads to the same soap service are executed at the same time or whether one will be blocking the other?

So we have multiple threads calling the **same soap service instance** like

```
class TestSoapRunner implements Runnable {
  private TestSoap testSoap;

  public TestSoapRunner(TestSoap testSoap) { // <- all threads use same TestSoap instance
    this.testSoap = testSoap;
  }

  public run() {
     ...
     testSoap.test();  // <- in multiple threads. is one call blocking others???
     ...
  }
}
```

and I need to know if only one soap call is executed at the same time i.e. one call blocks all other calls until it finishes; or whether all calls go through at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all go through at the same time.